# setting a variable for reuse using cypher - jquery

Tags: jquery, neo4j, cypher

What am I doing wrong? desc return undefined, everything is fine upto the last statement. desc has a value inside the function.

```
  function row_click(e)
  {
  var desc;
  var statement = "CYPHER runtime=compiled MATCH (m) where m.ID='" +e +"'    with m as m RETURN m.Description as desc";
      session.run(statement)
      .then (function(result) {
           var records = [];
           for (i = 0; i < result.records.length; i++) {
              records.push(result.records[i]);
              }
           return records;
          })
         .then(function(records){
             for(i = 0; i < records.length; i ++)
                  {
                      descrip=records[i].get("desc");
                  }
             desc= descrip;
         });
  console.log(desc);
  }
```